# Previewing line when drawing with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make a simple draw function to draw a line, but I want it to be previewed while it's being drawn; on EVENT_MOUSEMOVE it should draw the line continuously, while not saving it (e.g. how MS paint behaves when you draw a line and can see the output, which is saved when you release the mouse button).

I've used the "more advanced demo" [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html), where I use the input image as a global, make a copy of it, and then overwrite the image with the copy after drawing, but it doesn't actually make any difference (I neither see the "preview" of the line, and all the lines I draw stay on the canvas) and I can't see why:

```
img = None
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode,img
    img_c = img.copy()
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:

        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv2.line(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),1)
                img = img_c.copy()
            else:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:
            cv2.line(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),1)
        else:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)


while(1):

    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preview a line while drawing it, you need to update the image every time you move the mouse, but you need to keep the original to only draw one line. If the line changes orientation the idea is not to draw multiple lines, but to show only one line.

Here is a sample code of what I am talking about. I start with a black canvas, then I preview the line in blue, and once it is finish it becomes green. Read the comments inside the code to understand the details. If you have any questions just comment :)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# create black canvas of size 600x600
img =  np.zeros((600, 600, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# intialize values in unusable states
preview = None
initialPoint = (-1, -1)

# mouse callback
def drawLine(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global initialPoint,img, preview
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        # new initial point and preview is now a copy of the original image
        initialPoint = (x,y)
        preview = img.copy()
        # this will be a point at this point in time
        cv2.line(preview, initialPoint, (x,y), (0,255,0), 1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if preview is not None:
            # copy the original image again a redraw the new line
            preview = img.copy()
            cv2.line(preview, initialPoint, (x,y), (0,255,0), 1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # if we are drawing, preview is not None and since we finish, draw the final line in the image
        if preview is not None:
          preview = None
          cv2.line(img, initialPoint, (x,y), (255,0,0), 1)

# set the named window and callback          
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", drawLine)

while (True):
    # if we are drawing show preview, otherwise the image
    if preview is None:
      cv2.imshow('image',img)
    else :
      cv2.imshow('image',preview)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('q'):
      break;

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```